# Slicing two numpy arrays by Boolean of the first

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's say I have two numpy arrays, of the same length.

```
a = array([1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1])

b = array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

I can slice a so that I only get values of 1. So

```
a_slice = array([1, 1, 1, 1]).
```

How would I similarly slice b based on the positions where a = 1?

I would need

```
b_slice = array([0, 1, 1, 0]).
```

Answer (score 1):

You can slice be where a == 1 inside your first array.  By using `a == 1`.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1])
b = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])

_slice = b[a == 1]
print(_slice)
```

You can get all of the ones by using `a[a == 1]`, but that seems far less useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast `a` to `dtype` `bool`

```
b[a.astype(bool)]
# array([0, 1, 1, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use np.where

```
mask = np.where(a == 1)

a_slice = a[mask]
```

You get

```
array([1, 1, 1, 1])


b_slice = b[mask]
```

You get

```
array([0, 1, 1, 0])
```